# How do I build newlib for size optimization?

Tags: arm, embedded, gnu-toolchain, newlib

I'm building an arm-eabi-gcc toolchain with Newlib 2.5.0 as the target C library.

The target embedded system would prefer smaller code size over execution speed. How do I configure newlib to favour smaller code size?

The default build does things like produce a version of `strstr` that is over 1KB in code size.

Comment: How are you determining the size of `strstr`?  I'd be surprised if it were truely that large.  Size of object file for example is no measure of code size.

Comment: Note that sometimes compiling with -O2 produces a smaller binary than -Os, just try the different compiler options until you get what you want, and/or realize the uber generic function you might want to use, you could write a specific one that is likely much smaller.

Comment: @Clifford Looking in the linker map for the final executable

Comment: @M.M : OK, I guess it is that large!  It may be useful to specify the version of Newlib in the question..  If you look at the source strstr.c, there are two implementations; a much simpler/smaller one enabled by `#if defined(PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED) || defined(__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__)`.  Note that for long strings it is also significantly slower, but if you are that concerned about code size, perhaps long strings too are avoided?

Answer (score 3):

There is fat in Newlib that can be addressed with Newlib-nano, which is already part of GCC ARM Embedded, as discussed [here](https://community.arm.com/iot/embedded/b/embedded-blog/posts/shrink-your-mcu-code-size-with-gcc-arm-embedded-4-7) (Note the article is from 2014, so the information may be out-dated, but there appears to be Newlib-nano support in the current [v6-2017](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) too).

It removes some features added after C89 that are rarely used in MCU based embedded systems, simplifies complex functions such as formatted I/O, and removes wide character support from non-wide character specific functions.  Critically in respect to this question the default build is already size optimised (`-Os`).

Comment: The git repos for newlib-nano-1 and newlib-nano-2 don't seem very active;  the "newlib" part of the official "6-2017-q1-update" source package has later-dated files than any of those repos, so I guess they have their own private (unversioned?) fork of it

Comment: @M.M : Yes the status was rather unclear to me too,  The v6-2107 release notes give the same git reference for both Newlib and Newlib-nano (git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git commit e046e4de145009ae6baf27f8e0553a666e6a8d3d) suggesting perhaps that nano is absorbed into the main project.  Perhaps not a problem if you are using ARM's pre-built toolchain, but I appreciate that you may not want to do that.

Comment: I found an article on building a toolchain with nano. https://istarc.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/stm32f4-build-your-toolchain-from-scratch/  (again from 2014 though, and a separate repo).

Comment: OK, that link also references the same newlib-nano-2 repo (it's a fork but unmodified).  When I get time next I'll try building the nano from the v6-2017 bulk blob . (Actually it might be interesting to inspect the differences between that and what I did for binutils and gcc - I used them from their respective sites, not the ARM blob)

Answer (score 2):

Configure newlib like this:

```
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-DPREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED=1 -Os" \
../newlib-2.5.0/configure
```

(where I've omitted the rest of the arguments I used for configure, they don't change based on this issue).

There isn't a configure flag, but the configure script reads certain variables from the environment. `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` means flags used when building for the target system.

Not to be confused with `CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD` , which are flags that would be used if the build system needed to make any auxiliary executables to execute on the build system to help with the build process.

---

I couldn't find any official documentation on this, but searching the source code, it contained many instances of testing for `PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED` or `__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__`. Based on a quick grep, these two flags are almost identical. The only difference was a case in the `printf` family that if a null pointer is passed for `%s`, then the former will translate it to `(null)` but the latter bulls on ahead , probably causing a crash.